# Approximate inverse of large sparse matrix

Tags: matrices, oc.optimization-and-control, sparse-matrices

Given a large sparse matrix $M$, how to determine the existence of a good preconditioner? In other words, does there exist a sparse matrix $X$ such that $X M$ is close to the identity with respect to the Frobenius norm?

Comment: Have you tried something like the following regularization? $$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \left\| \mathrm X  \mathrm M - \mathrm I \right\|_{\text{F}}^2 + \gamma \left\| \mathrm X \right\|_1\\ \end{array}$$ where $\left\| \cdot \right\|_1$ is the sum of the absolute values of the entries. Varying $\gamma \geq 0$, interesting things may happen.